# Get text from select in HTML using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the value of a selected element and show it at the console. I've searched everything, tried everything and it's not working.
value1 I get it but value2 and 3 not.

If you have any other recommendation (besides using Jquery to do this, please do it)

Check it out

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $("button").click(function() {

            var value1 = $("#name-input").val();
            var value2 = $("#place-input").filter(":selected").text();
            var value3 = $("#tecnico-input").find(":selected").text();
            console.log(value1 + ' ' + value2 + ' ' + value3);
       
        });

    });
```

```html
<form>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Name:</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex.: John" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="name-input">
                </div>

                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sel1">Place:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="sel1" id="place-input">
                      <option value="1">Fixed</option>
                      <option value="2">Mobile</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sel2">Technician:</label>
                     <select class="form-control" id="technician-input">
                          <option value="1">Brandon</option>
                          <option value="2">Justin</option>
                          <option value="3">Ryan</option>
                          <option value="4">Tyler</option>
                     </select>
                </div>

        </form>
```

I strongly appreciate the help.

Comment: `$("#place-input").children().filter(":selected").text();`, `tecnico-input` != `technician-input`.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't define an elements ID twice, may be the opposite assignment that is taking precedence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dont use two id in one tag

```js
$("input[type='button'").on('click',function() {
   var value1 = $("#name-input").val();
   var value2 = $("#place-input option:selected").text();
   var value3 = $("#technician-input option:selected").text();
   console.log(value1 + ' ' + value2 + ' ' + value3);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="click" />
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Name:</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex.: John" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="name-input">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="sel1">Place:</label>
  <select class="form-control"  id="place-input">
      <option selected value="1">Fixed</option>
      <option value="2">Mobile</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="sel2">Technician:</label>
   <select class="form-control"  id="technician-input">
      <option  value="1">Brandon</option>
     <option value="2">Justin</option>
     <option selected value="3">Ryan</option>
      <option value="4">Tyler</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: very nice explanation. Thanks for the help. mistyping was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`.filter` applies the selector to the collection selected by the previous selector. But `:selected` doesn't apply to the `<select>` element, it applies to the `<option>` elements within it. Use `.find()` to search for an element within another element.

```
var value2 = $("#place-input").find("option:selected").text();
```

or more simply:

```
var value2 = $("#place-input option:selected").text();
```

Also, you can't have two `id` attributes in an element. `id="sel1" id="place-input"` should just be `id="place-input"`, and similarly for the other `<select>`.

Answer (score 1):

You have it right. You've just included two `id` attributes to each of your `select` tags in the HTML. HTML standards indicate only one `id` can be set for each DOM element. This means that if you replace the `id`s with the ones you use in the javascript code, or vice versa, you'll get the result you want with your `.filter(":selected").text()` code.